# Adjust sensitivity of setOnTouchListner in Android

Tags: android, view, touch-event, ontouchlistener

Is there anyway I can adjust the sensativity of the setOnTouchListner . Currently it is typing multiple values on each touch..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to register only one touch you can use something like this:

```
boolean taped=false;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(!taped){
            //do your stuff
        }else taped=true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        taped=false;
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @user1163234, then you should set OnClickListener instead